# How to order random in ServiceStack OrmLite?

Tags: mysql, ormlite-servicestack

I want to order by "NEWID()" or `Guid.NewGuid()` but couldn't make it work. I didn't find any examples or documentation about this subject.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Random ordering is specific to each RDBMS provider you would need to order by a custom SQL Function which you can do using a Custom SqlExpression, e.g. for SQL Server:

```
var randomRows = db.Select<Poco>(q => q.OrderBy("NEWID()"));
```

However I've just added support for the new `OrderByRandom()` API [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/41226795fc12f1b65d6af70c177a5ff57fa70334) which abstracts the way the RDBMS specific API's to retain a portable API that you can now query with:

```
var randomRows = db.Select<Poco>(q => q.OrderByRandom());
```

This change is available from v4.0.43+ that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's a shame I didn't mention that I was using MySQL provider. Is it also valid for MySQL?

Comment: @vardars Yeah `OrderByRandom()` also supports MySql which uses `RAND()`